# How to correctly scale images on hi-res-screens

Tags: java, swt

Our SWT-based Java application automatically uses the default font-size of the operating system and that to derive other fonts. Hence, the texts of the GUI look fine on hi-res-screens (e.g. 2880 x 1620 with Windows 8 being configured as "Larger" in Control Panel > Appearance and Personalization > Display). Unfortunately, the images are not scaled, so, e.g., tool bar buttons appear too small.

On OS X the hi-res-screen handling seems easy: the virtual resolution is just half of the size, but how to do the scaling on Windows which seems to allow non-integer scaling factors? How to detect when to scale and when not?

**Update**
It looks like [this SWT issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=462569) covers a similar problem.

Comment: I know you're aware of this bug report, but it may be useful to others: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=421383

Comment: Did you give the suggested API (in the link) a go? You can download SWT 4.5M6 to test it. I've started using it last week and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, they fix it only for images, but not otherwise, e.g. owner draw.

Comment: Well, your question seems to be about images, that's why I was asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Neon (4.6) M6 - New and Noteworthy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.6/M6/), the milestone release contains some automatic scaling for images (e.g. for toolbar).

**SWT provides resolution-based auto-scaling**

> SWT now automatically scales images on high-DPI monitors on Windows
>   and Linux, similar to the Mac's Retina support on OS X. In the absence
>   of high-resolution images, SWT will auto-scale the available images to
>   ensure that SWT-based applications like Eclipse are scaled
>   proportionately to the resolution of the monitor.
>
> [image]
>
> This feature can be disabled on Windows and GTK by setting this VM
>   argument to false in eclipse.ini or on the command line after -vmargs:
>
> -Dswt.enable.autoScale=false
>
> Auto-scaling cannot be disabled on the Mac as it is provided by the
>   OS.
>
> Caveats: We're aware that some scaled images look bad at scale factors
>   less than 200%. This will be improved in M7. Furthermore, we're
>   working on support for high-DPI images in Platform UI, so that plug-in
>   providers can add high-DPI icons without doing any code changes.

Or maybe this helps, in Eclipse Mars API for high resolution was added

> New APIs have been added to provide support for rendering
>   high-resolution images on high-DPI monitors. Two constructors have
>   been added to the Image class. They accept image-provider callbacks
>   that allow clients to supply resolution-dependent versions of images:
>
> ```
> public interface ImageDataProvider {
>   public ImageData getImageData (int zoom);
> }
> public interface ImageFileNameProvider {
>   public String getImagePath (int zoom);
> }
> ```
>
> Depending on the user's monitor configuration, SWT will request images
>   with the corresponding zoom level. Here's an example that displays 3
>   original images, followed by variants whose resolution changes
>   depending your monitor's resolution: [Snippet367.java](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/plain/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet367.java).
>
> Note that this is just the first step to support high-resolution
>   images in SWT and Eclipse-based applications. Work is underway to
>   adopt the new APIs in the platform. Futhermore, more work in SWT is
>   required to properly support drawing into high-resolution images via
>   GC.

**APIs for high-DPI monitor support**
http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2FwhatsNew%2Fplatform_isv_whatsnew.html

Comment: @flaviodonze What do you need to know for hi-res screens when using vanilla swing for the gui rather than swt ?

Comment: hi Paul, sorry I don't have any expertise in vanilla swing.